# unknown Bar in every Win CE Form

Tags: winforms, windows-mobile, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce

i am currently working on an App for Win CE 5.0 and every Form  start on my device with a bar over every object on my form.
Does anyone know something about this?
Better how to remove it...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a Form MainMenu with no items in it.  Just remove the MainMenu item from each of the Forms (or the base Form if they all derive from a common parent).